# Selenium Grid (RemoteWebDriver) usage with Cucumber jvm SharedDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, cucumber-jvm

I implemented cucumber-jvm picocontainer with SharedDriver and works well locally. I would like to use Selenium Grid which has been configured well but I don't know how should I modify `Shareddriver` class in order to use `RemoteWebDriver` instead of `WebDriver` and connect to Selenium GRID.

`new RemoteWebDriver(new("http://..../wd/hub"), capability);` doesn't work because I need to throw `MalFormedException` and `REAL_DRIVER` is a static field.

Any idea? Thanks!

```
public class SharedDriver extends EventFiringWebDriver {

    private static final WebDriver REAL_DRIVER = WebDriverFactory.internetExplorerWebDriver();
    private static final Thread CLOSE_THREAD = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            REAL_DRIVER.close();
        }
    };

    static {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(CLOSE_THREAD);
    }


    public SharedDriver() {
        super(REAL_DRIVER);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        if(Thread.currentThread() != CLOSE_THREAD) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "WebDriver should not close!"
            );
        }
        super.close();
    }

    @Before
    public void deleteAllCookies() {
        manage().deleteAllCookies();
    }

    @After
    public void embedScreenshot(Scenario scenario) {
        ...
    }

}
```

WebDriverFactory:

```
class WebDriverFactory {
    static {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/test/resources/webDrivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
    }

    static WebDriver internetExplorerWebDriver() {
        DesiredCapabilities returnCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/test/resources/webDrivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
        returnCapabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
        returnCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING, false);
        returnCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
        returnCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        returnCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
        return new InternetExplorerDriver(returnCapabilities);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the return statement into a `try..catch` block and return `null` in case of exception is being thrown.

```
class WebDriverFactory {
static {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/test/resources/webDrivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
}

static WebDriver internetExplorerWebDriver() {
    DesiredCapabilities returnCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/test/resources/webDrivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
    returnCapabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
    returnCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING, false);
    returnCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
    returnCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    returnCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);

    try {
        return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://www.google.com"), returnCapabilities);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

then, check that the `REAL_DRIVER` value is not `null`.

Comment: Strange, I tried to solve in this way, but it works now! Thanks!

Comment: I will ask another question, I do not want to devote it, but unfortunately it doesn't work however there is no compilation error.

Comment: Hi Eugene, please take a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231987/cucumber-jvs-selenium-grid-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-unable-to-cre  CucumberJVM SharedDriver doesn't work if I wanna use RemoteWebdriver instead of WebDriver. Any suggestion would be appreciated!